# How to read multiple .dat files and take maximums in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 10 .dat files in a folder. Is it possible to read all the files at once with MATLAB and do maximum of the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns of those 10 files? Note that all the files are similar, except the length of rows.

```
 WARNING from OUTDAT: variable DFS supplied without new independent TIME
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Output table number  :  0 (=first output table)
* Output table format  : Spreadsheet output
* Simulation results

TIME          WSO            LAI             DDTR             TMAX            TMIN            DVP             WNM             RAIN            IRRI            HI              TSN             TNUPT           DVS             DFS   ...

32.0000       0.0000         0.74441         2.64540E+07      29.700          16.200          61.594          2.8000          0.0000          0.0000          0.0000          0.0000          0.0000          0.0000          1.0000          0.0000          5.0000         9.90000E-04      45.116          22.558          22.558          0.0000          22.558          0.0000          
.             .               .               .               .               .
.             .               .               .               .               .
.             .               .               .               .               .
```

Comment: seems like a perfect file which can be handled by `importdata` function.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has a very nice import assistant function that will generate all the required code for you.

But if you prefer to program yourself have a look at the `dlmread` function.